# TouchableHighlight onPress not working on the first press React Native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm calling all the images from the media library and adding them to a flat list, I'm trying to add every image I press to a list, and it works but it takes few clicks until the image is added to the list, how can I fix it?

```
  selectImage = (index, item) => {
    let newSelected = { ...this.state.selected };
    if (newSelected[index]) {
        delete newSelected[index];
    } else {
        newSelected[index] = item
    }
    if (Object.keys(newSelected).length > this.props.max) return;
    if (!newSelected) newSelected = {};
    this.setState({ selected: newSelected })

    const arr = Object.keys(newSelected).map(key => {
        return newSelected[key];
    });
    console.log(this.state.selected);
    console.log(arr);
}
```

this is the image container where I use onPress.

```
renderImageTile = ({ item, index }) => {
    let selected = this.state.selected[index] ? true : false;

    if (!item) return null;
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight
            style={{ opacity: selected ? 0.5 : 1 }}
            underlayColor='transparent'
            onPress={()=>this.selectImage}
        >
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} pointerEvents='none'>
                <ImageBackground
                    style={{ width: width / 4, height: width / 4 }}
                    source={{ uri: item.uri }}
                >
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        </TouchableHighlight >);
}

render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;

    if (!hasCameraPermission) {
        return this.props.noCameraPermissionComponent || null;
    }

    let selectedCount = Object.keys(this.state.selected).length;
    let headerText = selectedCount + ' Selected';


    return (
        < View style={styles.container} >
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <Button
                    title="Exit"
                    onPress={() => this.props.callback(Promise.resolve([]))}
                />
                <Text>{headerText}</Text>
                <Button
                    title="Choose"
                    onPress={() => this.prepareCallback()}
                />
            </View>
            < FlatList
                data={this.state.photos}
                numColumns={this.state.numColumns}
                key={this.state.numColumns}
                renderItem={this.renderImageTile}
                keyExtractor={(_, index) => index
                }
                onEndReached={() => { this.getPhotos() }}
                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                ListEmptyComponent={this.state.isEmpty ? this.renderEmptyStay() : this.renderPreloader()}
                initialNumToRender={24}
                getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
            />
        </View >
    );
}
```

I want the onpress to work from the first try

Answer (score 0):

in your arrow function you are calling selectImage function but not triggering it
try out this

`onPress={()=>this.selectImage()}`